# Select > Dropdown accessiblity Issue

Tags: angular-material, accessibility, wai-aria

I have the following HTML code:

```
<mat-form-field >
 <mat-label>Favorite food</mat-label>
 <mat-select>
 <mat-option role="option" *ngFor="let food of foods" [value]="food.value">
 {{food.viewValue}}
 </mat-option>
 </mat-select>
 </mat-form-field>
```

and the below HTML is rendered in the browser after I run the application:

```
<mat-select _ngcontent-c12="" class="form-control mat-select ng-tns-c21-23 mat-
select-empty ng-star-inserted" role="listbox" id="mat-select-10" tabindex="0" aria-labelledby="mat-form-field-label-21" aria-required="false" aria-disabled="false" aria-invalid="false" aria-multiselectable="false">
<div class="mat-select-trigger" aria-hidden="true" cdk-overlay-origin=""><div class="mat-select-value" ng-reflect-ng-switch="true"><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-switch-case": "true"
}--><span class="mat-select-placeholder ng-tns-c21-23 ng-star-inserted">&nbsp;</span><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-switch-case": "false"
}--></div><div class="mat-select-arrow-wrapper"><div class="mat-select-arrow"></div></div></div><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-origin": "[object Object]",
  "ng-reflect-positions": "[object Object],[object Object",
  "ng-reflect-offset-y": "-12",
  "ng-reflect-min-width": "325",
  "ng-reflect-backdrop-class": "cdk-overlay-transparent-backdr",
  "ng-reflect-scroll-strategy": "[object Object]",
  "ng-reflect-open": "false",
  "ng-reflect-has-backdrop": "",
  "ng-reflect-lock-position": ""
}--></mat-select>
```

When I open the dropdown, I get this ng options:

```
<mat-option _ngcontent-c12="" class="mat-option ng-star-inserted mat-active" role="option" ng-reflect-value="value1" tabindex="0" id="mat-option-4" aria-disabled="false"><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
}--><span class="mat-option-text"> viewValue1 </span><div class="mat-option-ripple mat-ripple" mat-ripple="" ng-reflect-disabled="false" ng-reflect-trigger="[object HTMLElement]"></div></mat-option>
```

I am getting an error:  `Required ARIA child role not present: option`. I am new to this, and I have tried adding `aria-label`, and I gave an id to mat-options. It's not working. Can any one help me solve this one?

Comment: It sounds like you need to add missing `role` attributes.

Comment: i tried  by adding ` role="listbox" ` to `mat-select` tag, even though its not working

Comment: may be the versions that you are woking may be wrong

Comment: i am using the dropdown from angular material library

Comment: @SyedRasheed — Have you tried adding `role="option"` to the appropriate elements, as the error message suggests?

Comment: yes i have added but its showing the same error

Comment: The "listbox" and "option" roles are automatically added by Angular Material - you don't need to set them. See https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview#accessibility.

Comment: Any chance you can show us the rendered HTML? It's going to be tough to find people with expert knowledge of both WCAG and Angular.

Comment: @Josh updated the post with html.

Comment: I can't say for sure, but it's possible that you're getting this error message because there are child `div` elements inside the `listbox` role div that don't have the `role="option"` attribute set. I would recommend doing some testing with static code to see if you can get this error message to go away. If that does the trick, at least you'll know where to start working.

Comment: even when i run the accessibility test on the documentation page i am getting the same errors, can you check this link once and run accessiblity.
https://material.angular.io/components/select/examples

Comment: I think this is the first time you've mentioned anything about "accessibility test" which I assume means using Chrome's lighthouse tool.

Comment: Based on the latest comments on Material Angular's repo it seems this is still an issue unfortunately: https://github.com/angular/components/issues/11083

One alternative to get better a11y is to revert back to a native Select element and style it so that it's consistent with your designs.

Answer (score 3):

Problems with MatSelect and accessibility testing are known and remain unresolved so far. See https://github.com/angular/components/issues/11083 for details.

Answer (score 0):

No need to pass the role attribute. The error means that "option" is an invalid value or the attribute "role". It should work fine without it.